# A command which returns either a process ID, if running, or some other output if not?

Tags: shell, process, solaris

I'm looking for a command that will give me the PID, and it's not running it should give me some output other than blank.

In my program, sometimes the library I'm using gives blank output even if that process is running and I'm not able to detect whether the blank output is due to the libray or due to the process having stopped!

Changing the library call will take time, so I'm looking for suggestions of such a shell command as workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Finding PID's

There are other tools rather than `ps` for looking up processes based on their names.

```
$ pgrep name
```

#### Example

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 2556

$ pgrep sleep
2556
```

Above we can see the process named `sleep` is started and then backgrounded. If we use `pgrep` to look for processes with that name we get back its PID.

#### Checking status

As to your question about the output being blank. When commands return they'll often times return a status code that gets stored in a special variable, `$?` in Bourne shells, such as Bash. So you simply need to interrogate this variable's contents to find out if the process name you were looking for was present or not.

#### Example

Similar example using `sleep` again.

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 3228
```

Look for the PID of a process named `sleep`.

```
$ pgrep sleep
3228
```

Check its status variable, `$?`, a zero means it ran successfully, and found what we were looking for.

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Now if we look for a bogus process named `sleepy`.

```
$ pgrep sleepy
```

Not only do we get no output, but the status variable has a one in it, denoting that the command we ran, was unsuccessful in finding what we were looking for.

```
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine commands as follows:

```
ps <pid> || echo "message"
```

If the pid exist you will get pid else you will get message printed.

Comment: i got the idea.. but i dont know pid, i want to get it ..i know process name

Comment: hi again, i have tried with pgrep <process> || echo "message" and its working ..simple .thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'll attack the question from a different angle. The answer `pgrep <some string>` should really be your last choice. Let me explain why.

In any Unix/Linux OS there's no predictable way to figure out if 'a process' is running unless you have the PID of that process. All methods based on string pattern matching on the process' arg vector is doomed to fail sooner or later. Example: You may think that e.g. `pgrep mysqld` is just what you need to figure out if your MySQL database is running but fails the day somebody starts a second instance of MySQL on that host which would be a perfectly legal action.

Because of the problems in using string pattern matching when finding processes you'll experience that almost all 'professional' scripts use *the pidfile method*, i.e. they make sure that the PID is saved in a file when the process is started. The problem then becomes: "How to check if PID is running?" where you would generally do `ps -p xxxx -o pid=` which will return the PID itself if the process is running and otherwise nothing. The benefit of this command is that it is portable across Linux/Solaris/BSD.

I'll repeat myself: If you need to resort to something like `pgrep name` in your check script then you've done something wrong when you started the process. `pgrep name` should be the last option you try and is really only relevant if you do not control how the process is started. Also don't be fooled by blog posts on the Internet that will lead you to believe that Unix/Linux has the concept of a name for a process. In Unix/Linux there's no such thing as a process' name, at least not something even remotely unique. I wish there was, but there isn't. The *only* thing unique about a given process is the PID.